# Tomcat 7 SSL compatibility with iOS 9

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, ios9

Has anyone figured out how to make Tomcat 7 support SSL connections to iOS 9 apps without configuring an NSAppTransportSecurity exception in the app?

I know that iOS 9 requires TLSv1.2 and Forward Secrecy. In my server.xml file I tried removing all the references to older versions of TLS and for the ciphers I listed only the ECDHE variants, which I believe support forward secrecy. This not only failed to allow the iOS app to connect, but it also prevented Chrome and Safari from making an SSL connection to the same server.

Will it help if I upgrade to Tomcat 8?

Do I need a different version of Java and/or some add-on to Java? I'm currently using Java 1.7.0_85, which is what comes with Amazon's default Linux AMI and seems to be the latest version available.

Could the problem have anything to do with my certificate? It is a wildcard cert that I obtained from GoDaddy in May, so it is relatively new.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a scanner such as [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check your server configuration and simulate handshakes. After you undo your current changes back to what it was, run a check to see what exactly is missing in your configuration to support [iOS9's ATS requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html). You do not need to remove references to older versions of the TLS protocol and non FS ciphers.

Note: The [Dev version of SSL Labs](https://dev.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) includes an iOS9 ATS test simulation.